# Maven does not list current version of a library

Tags: maven, netbeans, maven-3

With a Maven 3 based project in NetBeans 8 beta, when I context+click on the "Dependencies" item of the "Projects" navigator and choose "Add Dependency…" menu item, I get a dialog box for searching the repository.

Every time I type in "slf4j-api" and choose the found item "org.slf4j : self4j-api", I get different results. Sometimes in the list of versions I get 1.7.0, sometimes 1.7.5, but never the latest: 1.7.6 available for download from the [slf4j download page](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html).

Why does the list change when I search and display a list a minute later?

So I got try a search for "logback-classic", and click on "ch.qos.logback : logback-classic". The greatest version number is 1.0.13. That was released in May of last year. Since then version 1.1.0 was released 2014-01-28, and 1.1.1 on 2014-02-05.

Why does Maven not offer these later versions?

Is it a caching problem? Is there some way to force the dialog in Netbeans to update its list of available versions?

Comment: It's a caching issue; Netbeans probably keeps a copy of the Maven index around. I've seen the same problem in Eclipse.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Perhaps a caching problem, but I don't see how. I installed NetBeans in the last couple weeks while those products were released months ago.

Comment: In Eclipse you have an option to download the index everytime you startup. I don't know if Netbeans has a similar option.

Comment: @BasilBourque: The Maven index is downloaded from the repository server that you use. It's a file which contains the list of all artifacts in the repo. It doesn't matter when you installed NetBeans since the file comes from somewhere else.

Comment: The point you folks are missing is that the versions list *changes*. I can open the list to see some recent versions, and close the list. I open the list again and see only older versions. Then I open the list a third time, I see some of the more recent versions but maybe not all than I saw the first time. May be a bug in NetBeans 8 Beta.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the same problem in Eclipse. It often happens when the IDE can't update it's cached copy of the Maven index.

A quick fix is to put the latest version that I know into the POM and build the project once. The IDE will then download the dependency and from then on, it will know that this version exists.

The longer fix is to look into your IDE's error log to find out why it can't update it's copy of the index files. Often, you need to configure your IDE to use the correct HTTP proxy settings.

Comment: That seems to be working. First I let the NetBeans "Add Dependency…" dialog install an old version. Then I open the *pom.xml* file and edit the version number to the known latest number. NetBeans immediately downloads and updates the items listed under "Dependencies" tree in the *Projects* browser. Does not explain the weird behavior of NetBeans "Add Dependency" dialog's search list, but may be an effective workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans index all maven repositories in order to find all dependencies and versions. It is a time consuming task so by default it is launched once a week.

If you want to refresh the index go to Tools > Option > Java > Maven > Index and click «Index now»

If you still don't find the last version of your dependency, it is probably that the library has not been uploaded to repositories. To configure repositories go to Window > Services > Maven Repositories.

The documentation is a little outdated but you can find more information, here : http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices#Dependency_management